# Nexus S 'flashes' screen when locking

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, lock-screens, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When I lock my Nexus S, the screen flashes once:

It turns black, then the home screen appears again very shortly, then it's black again.

Do you have this aswell with a **Nexus S on ICS 4.0.3**? Is there a fix?

Comment: I haven't seen this with CyanogenMod 7. It may be a software / your-specific-phone hardware issue.

Comment: I haven't seen this on my Nexus S, neither with Gingerbread nor Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: Do you use Voodoo Sound / Color? Any custom Kernel? Stock ROM or custom ROM?

Comment: @Leandros None of the above. I did not 'manipulate' the Nexus S in any way. No rooting, no change of hardware or software. I've only installed apps via Marketplace.

Comment: IMM76D also has this problem, in spite of reflash (stock rom)

Answer (score 1):

It's a software issue with Ice Cream Sandwich as far as I know, so no fix. It may only be present on certain models however, I only have anecdotal evidence for this but I have the issue on my Nexus S model IML74K but know someone with a different model of Nexus S and they don't seem to have the issue...

Comment: Ok, well I have the model number [GT-I9023](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_S#Variants).

Comment: I'll try and find out what my friends is and post back when I know.